# Reduce/Apply mismatch

Tags: clojure, apply, reduce

I'm using Clojure 1.8 and I expected reduce and apply to be output-wise equivalent for this particular example.

```
user=> (apply max-key val {:a 2 :bb 1})
[:a 2]
user=> (reduce max-key val {:a 2 :bb 1})
[:bb 1]
```

They look like they are not, could anyone explain why? Thanks

Comment: Why do you exepct them to be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` prepends the arguments to the call of `max-key`. `reduce` - on the other hand - reduces over `{:a 2 :bb 1}`, calling max-key with two arguments. The `val` is treated as [the initial value of the accumulator](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) in the reduce.

A `reduce` form that is equivalent to your `apply` would be:

```
(reduce #(max-key val %1 %2) {:a 2 :bb 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

`(reduce max-key val {:a 2 :bb 1})` uses `max-key` as the accumulator and `val` as the initial value. It effectively expands into:

```
(max-key (max-key val [:a 2]) [:bb 1]))
```

`(max-key val [:a 2])` is `[:a 2]` and `(max-key [:a 2] [:bb 1])`